# Android Firebase multiple authentication in a single app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been working on an app that requires two different authentication activities, one for customers and other for sellers. How can I implement this functionality in a single firebase app with two different kind of authenticated users? ( a seller can also be a customer but a customer can not sign as a seller unless he is registered as a seller)

Comment: This is limitation of firebase. You can do one thing make Two nodes Sellers and Customer at the time of registration if user select the user type then the uniques address(like email) you can store respectively  if customer then in customer node and if Seller then in seller node. When ever user logged in check the email of user in sellers table if email exist then open the sellers view else show Customer View.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha Thanks for your suggestion but I don't want to restrict the seller to seller section only. Consider the case of Amazon app, a seller can sell products as well buy products(can act as both seller and customer). Is there any way to divide the authentication table in two parts?

Comment: If you're creating users in Firebase database after they register then assign each user a field,e.g. accType where you can assign a value, either seller or customer. Then check for this value when a user logs in and display content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot classify users in Authentication part.
But you could do the difference in Database.
However, if you want to a kind of e-commerce app, you do not need to seperate people into two category.
If a user is created a market place you can provide him with a marketplace section. With this part he/she could organize his market, and he/she also could buy from other people. If he/she is not created any market place you simply do not provide marketplace at the beginning but you could ask the user do you want to open a market place. So by that way you provide user with the creating marketplace as an option.